# Copy index column as a new column

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this, with 'Time' as the index column

```
Time
2019-06-24 18:00:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:03:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:06:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:09:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:12:00           0.0
                          ...    
2019-07-23 17:48:00    182.693333
2019-07-23 17:51:00    183.226667
2019-07-23 17:54:00        183.72
2019-07-23 17:57:00    180.963333
2019-07-23 18:00:00       180.515
```

I have tried this code:

```
df['index'] = df.index
```

But what I get is an Index row added at the last row:

```
Time
2019-06-24 18:00:00                                                  0.0
2019-06-24 18:03:00                                                  0.0
2019-06-24 18:06:00                                                  0.0
2019-06-24 18:09:00                                                  0.0
2019-06-24 18:12:00                                                  0.0
                                             ...                        
2019-07-23 17:51:00                                           183.226667
2019-07-23 17:54:00                                               183.72
2019-07-23 17:57:00                                           180.963333
2019-07-23 18:00:00                                              180.515
index                  DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-24 18:00:00', '2019-06...
```

So the ideal output would be:

```
Index                           Time
2019-06-24 18:00:00            2019-06-24 18:00:00               0.0
```

Because I want to save the file as a text tab delimited file, with the output of the text file first column being time series index, separated by tab

```
2019-06-24 18:00:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:03:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:06:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:09:00           0.0
2019-06-24 18:12:00           0.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can rearrange the columns with list comprehension after you create the new column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Series, so use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) first for `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.reset_index(name='val')
df1['index'] = df1.index
```

Or create `Multiindex Series` first and then converting to `DataFrame`:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index,df.index], names=('index','time')) 

df1 = df.reset_index(name='val')
```